# Renderização de div fora das tags thead

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Eu estou criando um tabela nesse seguinte modelo

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped  table-colored ">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Código</th>
           <th rowspan="2">Descrição</th>
           <th rowspan="2">Quantidade</th>
           <th rowspan="2">Unidade</th>
           <div class='fornecedor-material-th'>
           </div>
           <th rowspan="2">Fornecedor Compra</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
       <tr>
            <div class='fornecedor-material-th-row2'>

             </div>
        </tr>
```

Porém quando é renderizado pelo navegador as divs ficam de fora da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara dentro de uma table vc ao pode usar tags permitidas. Tr td th tbody thead tfooter, vc não poder por uma div como filho direto de una tr, mas pode colocar a div dentro da th que eh o indicado